# How to get the position using fancycoverflow in android

Tags: android, image, position, swipe, coverflow

I've implemented the whole example from the below link but can't get the position of a particular image focused at center position.

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

So what I should do for this?

I've implemented the below code to my class:

**MainActivity.java**

```
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setAdapter(new FancyCoverFlowSampleAdapter());
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedAlpha(1.0f);
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedSaturation(0);
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setUnselectedScale(0);
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setSpacing(0);
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setMaxRotation(0);
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setScaleDownGravity(0.2f);
    this.fancyCoverFlow.setActionDistance(FancyCoverFlow.ACTION_DISTANCE_AUTO);
```

**FancyCoverFlowSampleAdapter.class**

```
public class FancyCoverFlowSampleAdapter extends FancyCoverFlowAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GlobalFields.arrlistFrames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int i) {
        return GlobalFields.arrlistFrames[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getCoverFlowItem(int i, View reuseableView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ImageView imageView = null;

        if (reuseableView != null) {
            imageView = (ImageView) reuseableView;
        } else {
            imageView = new ImageView(viewGroup.getContext());
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new FancyCoverFlow.LayoutParams(400, 500));
            GlobalFields.i = i;
            Log.e("FancyFlow adapter", "Position: " +i);
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(this.getItem(i));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I've implemented both the java classes and if I will run this code, on the first position of the image it will display the output like **Position: 0** but when I swipe the images from right to left, on the second image position it will give me the output like this **Position: 2** whereas this is wrong output.

So it will directly move from **position 0** to **position 2**, so I need your help to make it correct and on click of a button I have to pass this shape or image to the next activity.

Your valuable feedback and additional efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set for setOnItemSelectedListener. Refer below code

```
this.fancyCoverFlow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             Log.d("fancyFlowCurPos ", String.valueOf(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```